# Binding Apache EChart TreeMap in Grafana with JSON-API Datasource

Tags: grafana, echarts

We are in process to review **Apache ECharts** integration into **Grafana**.
We came ahead with most of other charts, but are blocked with 'Treemap'
We got some example demonstrations as in below link:
https://echarts.volkovlabs.io/d/FlnnZ4F4k/treemap?orgId=1&editPanel=6

But these are mostly dealing with Static data.
We are planning to use **JSON-API** Datasource.

As data expected by TreeMap is in hierarchical structure, so we are not able to get it working with JSON-API.

I can share demo  API I am trying to test with.
Its URL is https://2691b864-8804-4a6e-9bbb-21fbbe520f09.mock.pstmn.io/SLADummy

So can some share details on how to bind JSON-API Datasource to Apache Treemap in Grafana or any sample where its already implemented.

We are able to connect Treemap in Grafana with Static data.
But not able to bind it with dynamic JSON-API datasource

Comment: Whats the issue with passing the retrieved json to the chart via [setOption](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echartsInstance.setOption)?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @MatthiasMertens. I was actually facing issue while using setOption in MonacoEditor. But Now got it resolved. I will post my solution so if anyone have similar issue, it will help them.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using below Script which you can update in TreeMap Editior:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: URLToGetData,
  type: "GET",
  data: JSON,
  success: function (data1) {
        const unitName= replaceVariables('$Unit');
    alert(unitName);
    var option1 = {
      series: [
        {
          type: 'treemap',
          data: data1
        }
      ]
    };
    echartsInstance.setOption(option1);
  
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("err!");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**